# when using for loop in gulp, It gives me warning of MaxListenersExceededWarning, is there any other way to do it

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, warnings, css-purge

I am basically trying to use gulp in my nodeJS project where I want to make a separate css files for every view file (.ejs), and store it in a public/compiled/example/ folder.
The *example folder* will have the name of the ejs file, likewise I want to store every compile css file to a specific folder for every .ejs file.

**For example:** there are 10 .ejs Files in my views folder and I want to make 10 separate CSS files for every .ejs file with the name of that ejs file.

**Flow of task:**

1. Compare every ejs file with given css for classes (using gulp-purgecss)
2. Concatenate them in one css file (using gulp-concat-css)
3. Minify that css (using gulp-clean-css)
4. And Store it in a folder called public/complied/[ejs filename folder]/[ejs filename.css]

But Gulp does not have that functionality to do the above thing.

**My code:**

```
const Path = require("path");
const FS   = require("fs");
let Files  = [];
function getDirectoryName(Directory) {
    FS.readdirSync(Directory).forEach(File => {
        const Absolute = Path.join(Directory, File);
        if (FS.statSync(Absolute).isDirectory()) {
            getDirectoryName(Absolute);
        }
        else {
            return Files.push(Absolute.split('\\').join('/').split('.ejs').join('').split('views/').join(''));
        }
    });
}
```

Above code get all the names of the files present in the views folder and stores it in an array.

```
let bootstrap = src('public/css/bootstrap.min.css')
let style = src('public/css/style.css')
let icons = src('public/css/icons.css')
let colours = src('public/css/colors/default.css')
let tinySlider = src('public/css/tiny-slider.css')
//File Path Variables
const folderPath = 'views/';
const ejsExtension = '.ejs';
const cssExtension = '.css';
const jsExtension = '.js';

// CSS Task
function cssTask() {
    getDirectoryName("./views/");
    let bootstrap = src('public/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    let style = src('public/css/style.css')
    let icons = src('public/css/icons.css')
    let colours = src('public/css/colors/default.css')
    let tinySlider = src('public/css/tiny-slider.css')
    for (let i = 0; i < Files.length; i++) {
    merge(bootstrap, style, icons, colours, tinySlider)
        .pipe(purgecss({ content: [folderPath + Files[i] + ejsExtension] }))
        .pipe(concatCss(Files[i] + cssExtension))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(dest('./public/compiled/' + Files[i])
    );
    }
}
```

And this is the gulp code which runs a task.

**My error:**

> (node:15588) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added to [DestroyableTransform]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Gulp only runs once for whatever file I put in but I don't know weather it has any kind of inbuilt functionality that I can you for my project.

And the main thing is all the file is getting stored in the folder but it gives this warning with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I reformed some parts of this code, which works without errors.

1. Change the function a little bit.

```
function cssTask(fileName) {
  return src([bootstrapCss, styleCss, iconsCss, coloursCss, tinySliderCss])
    .pipe(purgecss({ content: [viewsFolderPath + fileName + ejsExtension] }))
    .pipe(concatCss(Path.basename(fileName) + cssExtension))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(dest(cssDest + Path.dirname(fileName)));
}

Note: Here cssDest is the destination folder you want to store the file in this case it would be "./public/compiled/".
```

2. I created a static Files array instead of getting the files name dynamically, with something like this:

```
let Files = ['about', 'contact', 'blog/index'];
```

3. At last I added a gulp task and wrapped it into a for loop of the Files array, so that gulp on 1 task at a time and handles 1 file at a time.

```
for (let i = 0; i < Files.length; i++) {
  task("css:" + Files[i], () => {
    return cssTask(Files[i]);
  });
}
```